# Trying to transpile TypeScript in WebStorm

Tags: node.js, typescript, webstorm

My WebStorm project on Mac has been setup with `tsconfig.json` in the root.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es5",
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "sourceMap": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "typings"
  ]
}
```

where the `typings` folder is at the root. Not sure if I need to "exclude" it but in either case I always get the following errors from WebStorm:

> Error:(683, 26) TS1110: Type expected.
>   Error:(1043, 33) TS1110: Type expected.
>   Error:(1055, 50) TS1110: Type expected.rver and server
>   gets the list on behalf of the user making the request.

I've tried various ways of installing the typings for node. My current setup is:

```
typings install dt~node --global --save
```

I must be missing a step. It would be really nice to user WebStorm. For now, VSCode is working fine and was really easy to setup.

Comment: How are you referencing to the definition files in your code?

Comment: See JetBrains' documentation on using Microsoft's language service within their IDE. https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2016.3/typescript-support.html